# How to match dictionary keys to model ids

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a list similar to the following:
`my_list = ['1', '2', '1', '3', '2', '1']`

These are votes and each vote is corresponds to an id from this model which contains the choices of a poll:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I'm using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the votes and I end up with this:

```
>>>votes = Counter(my_list)
>>>print(votes)
Counter({'1': 3, '2': 2, '3': 1})
```

Each key in this dictionary corresponds to an ID in the `Choice` model. How can I replace the key names of the dictionary with the corresponding `choice_text` for each ID?
I would like to end up with a dictionary that looks as following:

`{'choice_text for id=1':3, 'choice_text for id=2':2, 'choice_text for id=3':1}`

EDIT:Additionally what if I wanted to do the same procedure to the list I already have.

`my_list = ['1', '2', '1', '3', '2', '1']`

to something like this:

`another_list = ['choice_text for id=1', 'choice_text for id=2', 'choice_text for id=1', 'choice_text for id=3', 'choice_text for id=2', 'choice_text for id=1']`

Comment: What should happen if two `choice_text`s are the same (for different choices). If that can not happen, I would enforce that on the model level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well we can first load a dictionary that maps `id`s to `choice_text`:

```
mapping = dict(Choice.objects.filter(pk__in=votes.keys())
                             .values_list('pk', 'choice_text'))
```

Here with `pk__in` we thus make a filter (which is, strictly speaking, not necessary, but will reduce the amount of work both for the database and the webserver, unless the number of `id`s is huge). Then we want it to return `values_list`s, so for every element a list with two elements: the `pk` and the `choice_text`.

We use the `dict(..)` constructor, which can fetch an iterable of 2-lists (or 2-tuples), and converts it to a dictionary where for every element the left item of the sublist/tuple is the key, and the right item is the value.

Now we can use this to construct a new dictionary:

```
votes_with_text = {mapping[int(k)]: v for k, v in votes.items()}
```

Note that in case there are two `Choice`s with the *same* `choice_text`, then it will only retain *one* of the elements in the counter.

In case the `choice_text`s should be different for every two `Choice`s with the same `question`, you can enforce that at the model level with `unique_together`:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
       unique_together = (('question', 'choice_text'), )
```

Comment: I will make sure to enforce it in the model. But shouldn't the filtering include the `question` field too? Like so:

`mapping = dict(Choice.objects.filter(question = quesion_id, pk__in=votes.keys()).values_list('pk', 'choice_text'))`

Also can you explain what `pk__in` actually does?

Comment: @kstr: well the ids aitself are always unique, so if the `id`s all belong to the same question (which is likely the case), then these will all have the same question.

Comment: @kstr: updated with some extra information on the dictionary construction.

Comment: I have another similar question that is kinda off topic but I would really appreciate if you could answer.
What if I wanted to do the same but to the list instead of the dictionary?
`my_list = ['1', '2', '1', '3', '2', '1']`
to something like:
`another_list=['choice_text_id=1', 'choice_text_id=2', 'choice_text_id=1', 'choice_text_id=3', 'choice_text_id=2', 'choice_text_id=1']`

Comment: So `votes` is a list? Then change the `pk__in=votes.keys()` part into `pk__in=votes`, and the `votes_with text` to `votes_with_text = [mapping[k] for k in votes]`.

Comment: I meant do the same but to `my_list`. Just before the vote are counted and converted to a dictionary. I would like to end up with a list that has the original order but changes the ids to `choice_text`.

Comment: But a dictionary (and hence `Counter` as well, which is a subclass) *is* unordered. Once you throw data into a dictionary, the order of how it was constructed is lost, and therefore you can not reconstruct that later in the process. So I guess you will need to use an `OrderedDict` in that case.

Comment: @kstr: then for the mapping change it to `pk__in=mylist`, and `my_list_with_text = [mapping[k] for k in my_list]`.

Comment: I'm getting a weird error on this line:

`votes_with_text = {mapping[k]: v for k, v in votes.items()}`

`Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 
'83'`

83 is on of the id's in my dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

to get the name of your choice :

`choice_text = Choice.objects.get(pk=choice_id)`

so you have to iterate over your ids, get the choice_text and use :

`votes[choice_text] = votes.pop(choice_id)`
 
to rename your keys to the corresponding choice names.